# ALSA loopback device inside docker container

Tags: alsa, docker

I am trying to play and then record audio using ALSA inside a docker container, based on Ubuntu 16.04. Starting with a fresh container, I've tried following the example found [in the official ALSA documentation on the loopback device](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Matrix:Module-aloop), and using [QXIP/baresip-docker](https://github.com/QXIP/baresip-docker) as a starting point, but whenever I run `arecord -L`, I get the following message:

```
arecord: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
```

How can I initiate a loopback audio system inside a docker container?

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the required devices using the `--device` directive to `docker run`:

```
docker run --device=/dev/snd:/dev/snd
```

This makes devices under `/dev/snd/*` available to the container. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to Unix.stackexchange! I recommend you [take the tour](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour).